# Only want the first 100 entries in the new file

Tags: python

```
from Bio import SeqIO
path_to_file = ("/Users/richard/Desktop/AllSurfaceGlycoproteinSeqs.fasta")
with open(path_to_file, mode='r') as handle:
    out = open("/Users/name/Desktop/texas1.fasta", 'w')
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta'):
    identifer = record.id
    description = record.description
    sequence = record.seq
    if "TX" in description:
        out.write("{}\n".format(identifer))
        out.write("{}\n".format(description))
        out.write("{}\n".format(sequence))
       
out.close()
```

The code currently give me all couple thousand outputs but I only want the first 100 outputsin the new file created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a counter and  `break` when you have enough (not sure on which condition you want to count so I'll increment the counter on TX records):

```
with open(path_to_file, mode='r') as handle:
    out = open("/Users/name/Desktop/texas1.fasta", 'w')
    counter = 0
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta'):
        if counter >= 100:
            break
        identifer = record.id
        description = record.description
        sequence = record.seq
        if "TX" in description:
            counter += 1
            out.write("{}\n".format(identifer))
            out.write("{}\n".format(description))
            out.write("{}\n".format(sequence))
```

*NB. You don't need to create intermediary variables (`identifer = record.id`) you can directly do `out.write("{}\n".format(record.id))`*